# np.save is converting floats to weird characters

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, append

I am attempting to append results to an ongoing csv file. Each result comes out as an nd.array:

```
[IN]:  Print(savearray)
[OUT]: [[ 0.55219001  0.39838119]]
```

Initially I tried

```
np.savetxt('flux_ratios.csv', savearray,delimiter=",")
```

But this overwrites the old data every time I save, so instead I am attempting to append the data like this:

```
f = open('flux_ratios.csv', 'ab')
np.save(f, 'a',savearray)
f.close()
```

This is (in a sense) appending, however it is saving the numerical data as weird characters, as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

I have no idea why or how this is happening so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `np.save` does not write text whereas `np.savetxt` does. You are trying to combine binary with text, which is why you get the odd characters when you try to read the file.

You could just change `np.save(f, 'a', savearray)` to `np.savetxt(f, savearray, delimiter=',')`.

Otherwise you could also consider using `pandas.to_csv` in append mode.